# how to sign in on facebook from adobe flash game?

Tags: android, flash, air

I have developed a flash game for android. now the client's requirement is to connect with the social media like Facebook. Meaning : add a button to sign in on Facebook from that application itself. how does it possible?

Can any one help me here?

Comment: For that game i didn't have created separate .as file. It is integrated on keyframes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Register for a developer account on facebook.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/

2)Create a new facebook app.
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

3)Download Facebook-ActionScript API and store the .swc file in the libs folder in your project.
http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/downloads/detail?name=GraphAPI_Mobile_1_8_1.swc

4)Write facebook login code.
Maybe these links help you.
http://rjdesignz.com/adobe-flex/facebook-api-in-flex-mobile-air-app/ 
http://today-only.net/facebook_mobile/

Answer (score 0):

Register as a facebook developer->register application.
Use Facebook SDK 3.0 it has a examples for how to setup and login. You just have to put (copyd from my code):

```
login = (LoginButton) vju.findViewById(R.id.login_button);

<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

and this in the layout.xml